# Use Single button to toggle two functions for easy Light and Dark Mode

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code that allows me to easily switch from light mode to dark mode without having to write css for dark mode, it works with two buttons, each executing either the light mode or dark mode depending on your choice of click. However i want to merge this two functions into one single button so that it can be used to toggle the function. If anyone answering does include how it can be used with a toggle button, that won't be bad at all... The code i am using is

```js
const htmlEl = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

const toggleTheme = (theme) => {
    htmlEl.dataset.theme = theme;
}
```

```css
html {
    transition: color 300ms, background-color 300ms !important;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] {
    background: #000;
    filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)
}

html[data-theme='dark'] img {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleTheme('dark');">Dark Mode Test</button>
    
<button onclick="toggleTheme('light');">Light Mode Test</button>

<br><font color="red">WE ARE RED</font>
<br><font color="blue">WE ARE BLUE</font>
<br><font color="black">WE ARE Black</font>
```

Then i tried to execute the switch using Eventlisteners this way

```
<script>
   var btn = document.getElementById('navbtn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var foo = 'dark';
 
    if (foo === "light") {
        toggleTheme('dark');
    } else {
        toggleTheme('light');
    }

}, false);
</script>
```

This however only reacts on first click and not on second. What could be the best way to achieve this? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Sounds like a styled `checkbox` element to look like a button where you just toggle on the `checked` || `!checked` easy peasy for whomever wants the points.

Comment: @ChrisW. I'm not so good with JS so i always run into problems that may be easy peasy for a pro. Could you please provide an answer with stack snippet if you dont mind? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go, with some flare from a switch I made awhile back anyway. If you want verification just open your dev tools and watch the `data` attribute of the example HTML change live.

```js
const htmlEl = document.documentElement,
      outputExample = document.getElementById('output');
      
let savedTheme = 'light';

// ********************************************************************
//  NOTE: The localStorage example WILL NOT WORK HERE ON STACKOVERFLOW
//        Instead it will throw a "SecurityError" and rightfully so...
//        You'll have to use that part of the example in your
//        own project to see it in action...... JUST FYI.
//        So you will need to UNCOMMENT the commented out stuff for
//        the localstorage example to work. Left it commented out for
//        for other readers to not see the valid securityerror....
// ********************************************************************

// Toggle the theme and update their local storage.
toggleTheme = (bool) => {
   const theme = bool ? 'light' : 'dark';
   htmlEl.dataset.theme = theme;
   // localStorage.setItem('savedTheme', theme);
   
   outputExample.innerText = `${theme} theme`;
}

// Handle their saved preferred theme.
setSavedTheme = () => {

  // If there is no current theme in localstorage then give them one as a default.
  // Like for first time visitors...
  // Uncomment this block and the localstorage piece above for the localstorage example.
  /*
  if (localStorage.getItem('savedTheme') === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('savedTheme', savedTheme);
  } else {
    savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('savedTheme');
  }
  */
  
  htmlEl.dataset.theme = savedTheme;
  outputExample.innerText = `${savedTheme} theme`;
}

// Set the default.
setSavedTheme();
```

```css
.slide-toggle {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.slide-toggle input:first-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.slide-toggle input:first-of-type:focus ~ label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.slide-toggle input:first-of-type:checked ~ label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: darkorange;
}
.slide-toggle input:first-of-type:checked ~ label:after {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.slide-toggle input:first-of-type:disabled ~ label {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.slide-toggle label:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 4rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #777;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease, box-shadow 0.15s ease, color 0.25s ease;
}
.slide-toggle label:first-of-type:hover {
  border-color: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(225, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.slide-toggle label:first-of-type:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  right: 50%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.82, 0, 0.76);
}
.slide-toggle label:first-of-type:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px rgba(225, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.slide-toggle label:first-of-type div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

html {
  transition: background-color .3s ease;
}

html[data-theme="light"] {
  background-color: #fff;
}

html[data-theme="dark"] {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #212121;
}

body {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">

<div class="slide-toggle">
  <input id="guidLater"
         type="checkbox" checked
         onchange="toggleTheme(this.checked)"/>
  <label for="guidLater">
    <div><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></div>
    <div><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></div>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="output" style="margin-top: 1rem"></div>
```

Comment: You did the magic :) It Worked great and i'm sure on the long term this will come to the aid of many persons learning. Do you mind throwing a little light on why this worked as against what i was trying earlier?

Comment: The way you had it could have worked if you were storing the current state within the scope of your document somewhere. Like if you would have had a default value set to a var like `let currentTheme = true;` wherein `true` might mean "light" for example, and then in your function fired off from your click event you would toggle that boolean to use in a ternary* to set your theme string like onclick `currentTheme = !currentTheme` and then set your string like `htmlEl.dataset = currentTheme ? 'light' : 'dark';` so you just weren't giving it a way to know what it's toggling or how to deal with it

Comment: Also went ahead and expanded the answer a little for like you said...future readers. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for doing a great job with this. I'm having trouble storing the checkbox to localstorage and retrieving it.

Comment: @StevenHelson see updated answer, pay attention to the comments, commented out the localstorage stuff so readers dont get the valid securityerror crap. Have a good night and happy coding. 

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var foo = 'dark';
 
    if (foo === "light") {
        toggleTheme('dark');
    } else {
        toggleTheme('light');
    }

}, false);
```

Is wrong.

You need to grab the current theme from the clicked on element (you have it set in `data-theme` attribute of the element).

Your code just sets the theme as "dark" every time a button is clicked, rather than actually accepting the current value, and toggling it.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var currentTheme= event.currentTarget.dataset.theme;
 
    if (currentTheme=== "light") {
        toggleTheme('dark');
    } else {
        toggleTheme('light');
    }

}, false);
```

Also, remove your inline calls of `toggleTheme`, and only call the function from the handler on the `click` event listener.

```
<button data-theme="dark">Dark Mode Test</button>
    
<button data-theme="light">Light Mode Test</button>
```

Comment: This obviously is pointing out what is done wrong and not answering the question.

Comment: The text answers the question, telling you what to do, pointing out the exact reason your code is not working, and allowing you the chance to solve it yourself (a far superior learning experience)

I then updated the answer to provide code that will work.

Comment: Thanks but after using your updated answer, it still only toggles back to light, it doesn't toggle to dark when on light.

Comment: No problem! A further issue was that you are calling the `toggleTheme` function from the buttons, as an inline function call. You need to remove these inline function calls, and keep the function calls in the `click` event handler only.

(Better to separate JS from markup)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can toggle dark mode including CSS , hope it helps.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
  toggle.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark', e.target.checked)
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: background 0.3s linear, color 0.3s linear;
}

.toggle-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" />
  <label for="toggle">Toggle Theme</label>
</div>
<h1>this will change after toggle</h1>
```

Comment: Providing some explanation of what this code does and how it improves on the previous answers would make it more helpful.